# Short cut php echo code

Tags: php

I have a html table where i want to echo content out of a database table:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT Test FROM testtable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
echo $row->Test;
}
</td>
 <td>
<?php
$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT Test2 FROM testtable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
echo $row->Test2;
}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to cut short the php code, because it´s a bit too long to wirte in every

```
 <?php
 $ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT Test FROM testtable");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
 {
 echo $row->Test;
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you just query once to get all the data instead of running a query for every column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your example really is what you are doing you might want to rather get all data in a single query:

```
<?php
$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT Test, Test2 FROM testtable");
$recordset = mysql_fetch_array($ergebnis, MYSQL_ASSOC);
?>

<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach (array('Test', 'Test2') as $column) { ?>
                <td>
                    <?php foreach ($recordset as $record) { ?>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($record[$column], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                <td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also note that the `mysql_*` functions has been deprecated and will be removed from the language soon. If you want to make sure your code doesn't start throwing notices or even will stop functioning in the future you might want to start using either [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Also note that I have added [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent possible [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: I get an error which says: Illegal string offset 'Test' in....              <tr>
<?php foreach (array('Test') as $column) { ?>
<td>
<?php foreach ($recordset as $record) { ?>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($record[$column], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tr>

Comment: That would mean the sample code you provided is not the actual code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply do it by having a function:

```
function query($a){
$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT $a FROM testtable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
echo $row->$a;
}
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
 $a = 'Test';
 query($a);
 ?>
</td>
 <td>
<?php
$a = 'Test2';
query($a);
?>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function out of it. And use wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like this:

```
function query($a){
$ergebnis = mysql_query("SELECT $a FROM testtable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
echo $row->$a;
}
}
```